# My medium pages are noindex tag in header robots?

Tags: seo, backlinks, social-media, social-networking, social-login

my stories in medium have noindex tag. how i can do index them? thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is [consistent problem](https://medium.com/onely/mediums-got-a-large-problem-451bb89dfba7) with Medium.  Many people try to use Medium to just create backlinks to poor quality content.  As a result, Medium blocks indexing bots for a lot of content.  Until you have established yourself with multiple quality articles, Medium will block your content with no-index.

This article is also a [good explanation of why Medium blocks your content](https://medium.com/illumination/why-medium-wants-to-ban-your-story-from-google-720f9916dc0f) from being indexed.